# WordPress remove div around menu wrapping ul

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to remove the `div` that's wrapping my `ul` when I add a wordpress menu.

I've tried

> 'container' => false

But this doesn't seem to have any effect, unfortunately.

Is there any other way to remove the wrapping div?

Here's my full line

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('container' => false, 'container_class' => false, 'menu' => 1, 'menu_class' => 'nav nav-bar-right') ); ?>
```

Comment: have you tried `'container' => ''` ?

Comment: Can you please provide you full code for the block that menu is within. As it should not be outputting any surrounding elements. So the wp_nav_menu code you have is fine, something else is the issue. Could you also provide us with the code that gets generated, cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either pass the 'container' argument as blank string ( `container=>''` ) or don't set the container argument.